# Why "for" has been excluded?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I read this sentence in a story:

> "Could you come with me a moment, Joe," she said."

As a learner of English I would write this sentences as:

> "Could you come with me FOR a moment, Joe," she said.

Is it right to use "for"? Why hasn't the writer used "for"? Does it change the meaning?

Comment: It is casual speech and does not change the meaning.

Comment: Could you please come with me [for] a moment. It is spoken language and the for is left out. Either one is fine.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for the correction. I am a learner of English and do make mistakes.

Comment: You can say English learner. :)

Comment: @Lambie Seriously... this is a site for English _learners_. Your comment comes across very critical and unwelcoming. A bit of tolerance for imperfect grammar is a completely reasonable expectation here.

Comment: @TypeIA You are wrong about that. I enclosed it in brackets and the OP **thanked** me. The point of it is to use their posts and help them correct grammar so they can get better "in the heat of the moment".  Then, when they do, I delete my comment. That is how one actually learns a language. It has nothing to do with tolerance. Of course, if you've never taught or learned another language, you might not be aware of this.

Comment: TypeIA I agree with you 100%. The comments from Lambie are very unwelcoming and a nuisance. I am a native speaker and all I’m trying to do is help English Learners by telling them how I WOULD use a word in a CONTEXT in MY REGION. @Lambie please get a life that involves something other than criticizing strangers on the internet who are only trying to help. Your opinion isn’t the only opinion nor is it the only way to interpret something...

Comment: @user136000 How did I criticize a stranger who was trying to help? It seems you and Type1A are bent on making personal comments to me as you misunderstand what I was doing.

Comment: @Lambie you made comments about my capitalization and stuff, when i literally just have autocaps off on my phone settings, i know what should be capitalized— and to Type1A you disregarded them by saying “you are wrong about that” and told them they don’t understand the concept of language learning (but they are on this website). clearly you can’t take anyone else speaking up for you doing ignorant things... oh well but i’m glad that you are perfect in each and every way! i hope you have a w o n d e r f u l day :)

Comment: @user136000 Yes, no caps or punctuation were visible, and your answer is really a comment. Generally, people explain an answer, sometimes with references. So, it really looked like you were text messaging a friend. The answers here on this site are generally a little more formal than that. And I was pretty gentle because it was the kind of answer a mod would go after and I was trying to spare you that. There is no evidence that for or lack of for is British English. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an example of casual language, but I don’t see it much in America. It might be something written from a while ago or could be British English. The meaning is the same though!

Comment: Lambie I fixed it.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer